# How to get OpenStreetMap access token with devise omniauth-osm

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, openstreetmap, omniauth

In my controller, I'm trying to get an access token to OSM.

```
class Auth::OauthController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController

def osm
  @user = AppUser.from_omniauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"])

  token_req = request.env["omniauth.auth"]['extra']['access_token'].consumer.get_request_token(:oauth_verifier => params['oauth_verifier'])   

  @user.token = token_req.token
  @user.token_secret = token_req.secret

  sign_in_and_redirect @user
end

end
```

When I get the access token and writes it to the database.

Next, I try to use the OSM API through oauth gem.

```
@consumer=OAuth::Consumer.new Settings.osm.consumer_key, 
                          Settings.osm.consumer_secret, 
                          {site: osm_uri}

@access_token = OAuth::AccessToken.new(@consumer, current_user.token, current_user.token_secret) 

puts @access_token.get('/api/0.6/user/preferences').body
```

However, this code does not work in the console I see the authorization error

Comment: What error are you seeing exactly?

Comment: OAuth::Unauthorized: 401 Unauthorized

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the error in this code:

```
token_req = request.env["omniauth.auth"]['extra']['access_token'].consumer.get_request_token(:oauth_verifier => params['oauth_verifier'])   

@user.token = token_req.token
@user.token_secret = token_req.secret
```

correct code

```
@app_user.token = request.env["omniauth.auth"]['credentials']['token']
@app_user.token_secret = request.env["omniauth.auth"]['credentials']['secret']
```